# Postgresql 9.4 Cascading replication failover

Tags: postgresql, replication, cascade, postgresql-9.4

#### Environment:

```
Ubuntu14.04 + Postgresql9.4.
```

The following is my setup: ('->' denotes physical streaming replication PSR)

```
Master1 -> Slave1 (primary) -> Slave2
```

This behaves correctly - changes on Master1 reflect in Slave1, and then Slave2.

If I disable Master1, and promote Slave1 to a Master using a trigger_file  then Slave1 is promoted successfully - I can write to Slave1.

However, replication **ceases** between the newly promoted Slave1, and Slave2.

Is this the expected behaviour? I was expecting replication to continue like so:

```
Slave1 -> Slave2
```

Such that a write to Slave1 is reflected in Slave2

## Update

**Logs:**

#### Slave1 promoting:

```
2017-10-03 16:43:20 BST  @ LOCATION:  libpqrcv_connect, libpqwalreceiver.c:107
2017-10-03 16:43:25 BST  @ FATAL:  XX000: could not connect to the primary server: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "192.168.20.55" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

2017-10-03 16:43:25 BST  @ LOCATION:  libpqrcv_connect, libpqwalreceiver.c:107
2017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ LOG:  00000: trigger file found: /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main/failover_trigger.5432
2017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ LOCATION:  CheckForStandbyTrigger, xlog.c:11440
2017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ LOG:  00000: redo done at 0/19000740
2017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ LOCATION:  StartupXLOG, xlog.c:7032
2017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ LOG:  00000: last completed transaction was at log time 2017-10-03 16:41:23.430752+01
2017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ LOCATION:  StartupXLOG, xlog.c:7037
2017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ LOG:  00000: selected new timeline ID: 2
2017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ LOCATION:  StartupXLOG, xlog.c:7153
2017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ LOG:  00000: archive recovery complete
2017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ LOCATION:  exitArchiveRecovery, xlog.c:5459
2017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ LOG:  00000: MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ LOCATION:  DetermineSafeOldestOffset, multixact.c:2619
2017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ LOG:  00000: database system is ready to accept connections
2017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ LOCATION:  reaper, postmaster.c:2795
2017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ LOG:  00000: autovacuum launcher started
2017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ LOCATION:  AutoVacLauncherMain, autovacuum.c:431
```

#### Slave2

```
2017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ LOG:  00000: replication terminated by primary server
2017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ DETAIL:  End of WAL reached on timeline 1 at 0/190007A8.
2017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ LOCATION:  WalReceiverMain, walreceiver.c:446
2017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ LOG:  00000: fetching timeline history file for timeline 2 from primary server
2017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ LOCATION:  WalRcvFetchTimeLineHistoryFiles, walreceiver.c:669
2017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ LOG:  00000: record with zero length at 0/190007A8
2017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ LOCATION:  ReadRecord, xlog.c:4184
2017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ LOG:  00000: restarted WAL streaming at 0/19000000 on timeline 1
2017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ LOCATION:  WalReceiverMain, walreceiver.c:374
2017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ LOG:  00000: replication terminated by primary server
2017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ DETAIL:  End of WAL reached on timeline 1 at 0/190007A8.
```

#### Slave1 IP:

```
192.168.20.56
```

#### Slave2 IP:

```
192.168.20.53
```

pg_hba.conf allows Slave2 to connect to Slave1 for replication:

#### Slave1 pg_hba.conf segment:

```
host    replication     replication     192.168.20.53/32        trust
```

#### Slave1 recovery.done:

```
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'user=replication host=192.168.20.55 port=5432 sslmode=prefer sslcompression=1 krbsrvname=postgres'
trigger_file = '/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main/failover_trigger.5432'
```

#### Slave2 recovery.conf:

```
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'user=replication host=192.168.20.56 port=5432 sslmode=prefer sslcompression=1 krbsrvname=postgres'
```

Any help is very much appreciated on this.

#### Update and Solution

Thanks to `@Vao Tsun` answer, adding the recovery_target_timeline set to 'latest' in the Slave2 recovery.conf, and restarting Slave2 postgresql server (not reload) allowed the replication process to restart:

```
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'user=replication host=192.168.20.56 port=5432 sslmode=prefer sslcompression=1 krbsrvname=postgres'
recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'
```

Comment: please update post with logs and also check if you had timeline='latest' in slave2 recovery conf - to switch over next timeline when you promote slave1

Comment: I have updated my question with the log files of slave1 and slave2, as well as my recovery.conf files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you see in slave1 logs:

```
2017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ LOG:  00000: selected new timeline ID: 2
```

and in slave2:

```
017-10-03 16:43:30 BST  @ DETAIL:  End of WAL reached on timeline 1 at 0/190007A8.
```

so slave2 did not switch over to timeline two after the promotion.

as I said in comments, You need `recovery_target_timeline='latest'` in slave2 recovery.conf

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/recovery-target-settings.html

> recovery_target_timeline (string) Specifies recovering into a
>   particular timeline. The default is to recover along the same timeline
>   that was current when the base backup was taken. Setting this to
>   latest recovers to the latest timeline found in the archive, which is
>   useful in a standby server. Other than that you only need to set this
>   parameter in complex re-recovery situations, where you need to return
>   to a state that itself was reached after a point-in-time recovery. See
>   Section 25.3.5 for discussion.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. a restart of Slave2 with this field set in recovery.conf restarted the replication.

Comment: glad it helped!